# Linkedin REST API Job Search

Tags: linkedin-api

I've seen several posts linked to this question (some older than others) but no definitive answer.

I want to set a section on my web-page linking to the LinkedIn positions that answer to a particular, kind of specific, query.
Ideally, I would like to download and reprocess the text to mix Linkedin's job offers up with other sources and implement a layer of processing on all job positions relating to my user's needs.

Overall, what I do need is scraping LinkedIn Job Offers. I'm not too fond of the idea of implementing a scraping tool or using some external and non-supported plugin.

I've tried opening a request to LinkedIn, and I've been told I should write here with the #linkedin tag so that LinkedIn technicians' can see my bid and answer.

I have the impression that a LinkedIn API allowed searching for Job Posts/Positions and downloading the main, but the functionality it's not supported anymore. Does anyone know if that's the case or what I should do to perform that operation if that's not the case?

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to figure this out, too; back in the day, all the Job data was available for use; now, if you want to source Job listing data in your application, you have to purchase it through a data broker.

I have been looking at Datarade https://datarade.ai/search/products?keywords=job%20postings Linkedin, and all the other sites are selling their Job postings to data brokers.

LinkedIn, Indeed, etc., have all removed the API access to their hosted job data.

Answer (score 0):

In early 2024, you can also explore external Linkedin APIs on marketplaces like [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/category/Jobs), [APIlist](https://apilist.fun/category/jobs), or [APIfy](https://apify.com/store/categories/jobs)

There are APIs that offer the job postings from Linkedin and many other job aggregators, job boards, or company career pages such as:

- https://apify.com/bebity/linkedin-jobs-scraper
- https://rapidapi.com/bebity-bebity-default/api/linkedin-jobs-scraper-api/
- https://jobdatafeeds.com/job-api